# Executing R scripts in Symfony2

Tags: r, symfony, symfony-2.1, filepath, symfony-2.0

I have to execute (safely) a lot of **R scripts** from a **Symfony2** controller.
I organized in my `AcmeStatsBundle` a folder named `RScripts`. There, a lot of R script files are stored, e.g. `Test.R`
To execute the script in the *Test.R* file, I should write in my secured action something like:

```
$rootdir = ...//get the path to the src folder.
exec("Rscript $rootdir/Acme/StatsBundle/RScripts/Test.R");
```

Which is the command to use to get the right value for `$rootdir`? Maybe I'm wrong and I should deploy the scripts in the app folder.
Where should I put the generated output (e.g. images), in the web folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be :

```
$rootdir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '\..\src'
```

(what's those '\' is that some windows thing ?)

Comment: I suppose that the output files should be put in the web dir! Am I wrong?

Comment: Output files should be in the web dir, can you configure this in your R scripts ?

Comment: :) Yes, '\' is from Windows. Fill free to edit my answer and to put the example in Linux style!

Comment: Yes, you should keep your Rscripts in app/Resources/RScripts. If you can configure your RScripts to output to the web dir (../../../web/someDir) that's good.

Comment: Yes, R can be configured in that way. I will put output files in the `web/bundles/acmestats/images` folder

Comment: You'd better have a web/scriptOutPutImages/ folder, the web/bundles/acmestat is generated by php app/console assets:install and represents files in your AcmeStatsBundle/Resources/public. Replace "scriptOutPutImages" by a names that fit. By the way : apparently you can also use '/' in windows (or the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant) : http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary

Comment: Yes, you are right. I read that post some times ago. I have too much things in my mind and sometimes I feel confused, e.g. when I write echo in a Java code and I don't understand why it is not ok! Thanks! LOL

Comment: Is there any way to configure the creation of the "scriptOutPutImages"  folder? Should I put it in app/Resources?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22406/discussion-between-julien-and-jeanvaljean)